# Describing the space of matrices which "jordanize" a given matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, jordan-normal-form

This is a naive linear algebra question. I apologize for the level but I could not find an answer in the literature.

Let $A$ be a $n$ by $n$ matrix (say over $\mathbb C$). Suppose the Jordan form of $A$ is the matrix $J_\lambda$, for some partition $\lambda$ of $n$. My question is: how can one describe the set of invertible matrices which "jordanize" $A$? In other words, I would like to have an explicit description of $$G_A=\{M\in \textrm{GL}_n\,|\,M^{-1}AM=J_\lambda\}\subset \textrm{GL}_n.$$ 
I remember some time ago I thought the answer would be that $G_A$ is a product of $\mathbb C^\ast$, as many as there are distinct eigenvalues for $A$, which can be read off from $\lambda$. But now I was looking at a specific example more closely and I am unsure how one would go about proving that. Any help or reference is very much appreciated!

**Added**. For instance, if $n=2$, one can check by explicit computation that for the (already jordanized) matrix 
$$A=
\begin{pmatrix}
\eta & 0\\
0 & \mu
\end{pmatrix},\qquad \eta\mu\neq 0,\,\,\,\eta\neq \mu,
$$ 
one has $$
G_A=\Big\{\begin{pmatrix}
a & 0\\
0 & b
\end{pmatrix}:a,b\in\mathbb C^\ast\Big\}=\mathbb C^\ast\times \mathbb C^\ast.
$$
I wonder if one can be as explicit as this (expressing $G_A$ in terms of $\mathbb C^\ast$ or maybe $\mathbb C$) for any matrix of given Jordan type.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that both $M$ and $N$ are in $G_A$.  Then
$$
(A =)\; MJM^{-1} = NJN^{-1} \implies\\
J = (M^{-1}N)^{-1}J(M^{-1}N) \implies\\
(M^{-1}N)J = J(M^{-1}N)
$$
In other words: fix any one element $M \in G_A$.  Let
$$
C_J = \{X \in GL : XJ = JX\}
$$
Then $G_A = \{MX: X \in C_J\}$.  Note also that $C_J$ may be thought of as the kernel of the linear map $X \mapsto XJ - JX$.

---

Note: if $J$ is block diagonal with
$$
J = \pmatrix{
J_1\\
&J_2\\
&&\ddots\\
&&& J_k
}
$$
Where each $J_i$ is a Jordan block, then a matrix will commute with $J$ if and only if it is block diagonal of the same shape and corresponding blocks commute.

Comment: Yes, this is a nice way of rephrasing the problem, but I would not call it an explicit description of $G_A$. For instance, there may be "repetitions" in $\{MX:X\in C_J\}$. I added an example of computation of $G_A$ (in this special case, already jordanized, this coincides with $C_J$), to explain what I mean by "explicit".

Comment: I don't know what you mean by repetitions.  Multiplication by $M$ is invertible, so there is a one to one correspondence between $C_J$ And $G_A$

Comment: Also, you may find the computation of the commutant easier if $J$ is in [Weyr canonical form](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weyr_canonical_form) instead.

Comment: I see. So the answer is $C_J$ for every $A$ of Jordan type $J$. I wonder if one has a general description of this commutator in general.